# Determining a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

If $a>0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$, let $X\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ be the set $$X=\{(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2\;\}\{\;|1-zw|^2=a, \quad |z|^2-|w|^2=b\;\}.$$

Is $X$ a closed surface? This is what I expect because $X$ is defined by two equations. Also, how can I compute the homology of $X$ (if $X$ is a surface, I'd like to determine which one it is. Probably not a sphere.)?

Maybe this is obvious. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "surface"? As in 2 dimensional manifold?

Comment: Yes, a smooth 2-manifold without boundary.

Comment: Usually people intend "closed surface" to be a *compact surface with no boundary*.  I would wager here that $X$ is non-compact. You also might want to think carefully about the special case $a=1$. You're going to have to check that $(a,b)$ is a regular value of the map $\Bbb C^2\to\Bbb R^2$ to be sure that $X$ is a smooth manifold.